# Convert .shp file to comma separated value file

Tags: c#, gdal

How to convert shape(.shp) file to .csv file in C# ?

Comment: What you've tried so far?

Comment: I'm trying to modify the code from the below url and trying to save as csv file 

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/101552/shapefile-to-geojson-conversion-using-c?newreg=73bee43474bc42949179877ffd2cd077

but not able to read the actual data from the .shp file

Comment: I doubt that a shp file CAN be output to a csv.  It's not 2d style data.  Are you able to use a json file?